# Tehilim 47 - said 7 times before the blowing of the Shofar

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

What is the source and reason for saying [Tehilim 47](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2647.htm) - 7 times before the blowing of the Shofar?

Comment: Just had a great discussion about this today! Hint: Go to New Haven for R"H to find out. :)

Comment: @SethJ: What does New Haven have to do with this?

Comment: A friend will be speaking there about this.

Comment: @SethJ: Perhaps you can get your friend to post an answer here.

Comment: I'll suggest it, but I don't know if he will have the time.

Comment: This should answer your question http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2012-05-11_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf

Comment: New Haven's not too far away...where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rivevos Ephraim 6:309:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&st=&pgnum=392) notes that the Arizal instituted the seven times; he also cites the Imrei Emes ( קרח שנת תרע"ו ) who cites the Arizal and gives a reason; see there. See also Likutei Maharich 3:70.

In addition: The Tamei Minhagim 717 brings that there are 587 letters n the psalm; 587 is the gematria of the word Shofar with itself (im hakollel).